# NHibernate - what is the difference between ManagedWebSessionContext and WebSessionContext?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

In NHibernate, what is the difference between ManagedWebSessionContext and WebSessionContext ? Which is best to use, and why ?

Based on the [description found here](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-2/1nr4enxv3dpeq/6#2(2E)3(2E)(C2)(A0)Contextual_Sessions), I cannot tell the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same question recently and as far as I could determine ManagedWebSessionContext has been [deprecated](http://www.mail-archive.com/nhibernate-development@googlegroups.com/msg02339.html) and may be removed in version 3.0. Using WebSessionContext allows you to use the same session creation API with web, thread static, and call context sessions, and that's a compelling reason to choose it over ManagedWebSessionContext.